# What is the difference between the "war" and "warfare" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

They have different descriptions so I'm guessing they're not synonyms for each other. The descriptions don't seem to clearly make a difference between the two, however. Is one supposed to be used for a specific instance of war, and the other for questions about general warfare/tactics/strategy?

Answer (score 2):

The way I understood it, [war](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war) is for questions on specific wars (perhaps ones that aren't covered by existing tags like ww1?), e.g. [*What would've been the outcome of the Yom Kippur War had the UN not intervened?*](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/19039/what-wouldve-been-the-outcome-of-the-yom-kippur-war-had-the-un-not-intervened) In contrast, [warfare](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) would be for the history of waging wars in general, e.g. questions like [*When was the first airborne combat drop?*](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23848/when-was-the-first-airborne-combat-drop)

As is typical with such tags, in practice they get mixed around a lot. I think that in this case though there's a non-trivial difference and on the whole I think people (or editors) are tagging them differently.

Comment: Should OP (or editor) just replace the war tag with a war-specific tag then? I don't see the utility in a tag for "leftover wars"

Comment: @twosheds Well, I can see it being helpful for someone interested in, say, medieval wars. Of course in that case we'd want the war tag on questions covered by specific names too. Without a hierachial tag system we're not going to get a perfect solution I suppose.